# Cannot insert same object after deleting

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android studio and developing an android app for an assignment. Customer can add items to 'cart' as well as remove them from the cart. If I remove an item from the cart, I can't insert the same item(by using an object) to the cart again. In firebase database, values are removing as soon as they get inserted
Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

I tried finish() method but it didn't solve this

```
**Method to delete an item**

btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CART).child(NIC);
                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(itemNo.getText().toString())){
                                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CART).child(NIC).child(itemNo.getText().toString());
                                databaseReference.removeValue();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cart.class);
                                intent.putExtra("NIC", NIC);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are caught in a loop, the `ValueEventListener` stays listening to changes so after you press the button the listener is still active. Everytime a new object is created the listener is triggered and execute that piece of code which means it will delete it.

What you are trying to do is to validate if the value exist, if it does exist then you remove it.

For doing it this way you can just change the current method for `addValueEventListenerForSingleEvent`

But this is not needed because if you try to delete and there is nothing, nothing bad will happen, so try with this inside the click listener, for simpler version:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CART).child(NIC).child(itemNo.getText().toString());
databaseReference.removeValue();
```

If you really want to validate the item exist then use a `transaction`

Comment: Welcome, can you thank by marking the answer as resolved?

Comment: I tried but my reputation isn't enough. I'm sorry!!

Comment: I think there is a wait for answers period, maybe it will remind you with an email, anyway, give it a try in a couple of daya, best of luck with your assigment